# AWS set s3 bucket directory access with policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a policy on [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) that allows access to specific folders in an s3 bucket. According to the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) this can be done with the following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-policy-test"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "home/",
                        "home/test-folder1"
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [
                        "/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-policy-test"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "home/test-folder1/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-policy-test/home/test-folder1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I created a user to check if this policy works as intended, but unfortunately it doesn't. When I log in with the test user I am able to see the folders in the bucket, but I can't access the one that I want called "test-folder1".

**Question:** How do I change this policy so that allows access to test-folder1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `home` folder in your S3 bucket? You're referring to the `home` folder in your policy, but you don't mention it in your test with a test user.

Looking at the policy, I would expect the following S3 structure:

```
arn:aws:s3:::my-policy-test
- home
- home/test-folder1 (should have the rights here)
- other_folder
```

This should work given your policy.